# SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer abort, OperationAbortedException?

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I'm currently running two tasks which are copying data to my SQL Server. The data copying is done by the method `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`. I'm using the `SqlRowsCopiedEvent` to show the user the amount of rows that are successfully copied. Every time this event is called I'm checking if the cancellation token is requested. If the token is requested (button click) I'm setting `SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs.Abort` to `true`. This aborts the `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` method.

Now I'm getting an `OperationAbortedException`. I looked at the documentation and it says that this exception is thrown whenever the user is cancelling an operation. However I'm not 100% sure if it's right that this  indeed throws when I abort the write to server method?

Comment: it isn't amazingly surprising that setting `Abort` to `true` results in an `OperationAbortedException`...

Comment: Yes, I indeed thought the same. However I want to be sure it is normal that that exception is thrown.

Comment: You say that the documentation states that this exception is thrown in exactly this case. Why do you still wonder something might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that this exception is thrown in this case. This is normal behavior.